# Xcode 5.1 enable C++14

Tags: xcode, clang, c++14, xcode5.1

Xcode 5.1 using Clang 3.4. And Clang 3.4 supports C++14.

However, I've been surfing though all of the Xcode options and don't see a way to enable C++14.

I'm trying to enable the relaxed *constexpr* feature of C++14

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about finding a button in an IDE.

Comment: And that is a problem, why?. The whole world does not revolve around a command line (in fact very little of it does)

Comment: There is an Xcode tag here with 5200 followers. Why would you think an Xcode-related question is not appropriate on stackoverflow?

Comment: Programming is not only about algorithms, it involves a wide range of problem solving.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To get this to work, you first set "C++ Language Dialect" to "compiler default". Then in "Other C++ flags" add "-std=c++1y".

This will allow Clang++ to compile with c++14 from within Xcode. I tested this with Xcode 5.1.1 using the new user defined literal for basic_string:

```
std::string word = "hello"s;
```

Update: As of Xcode 6, c++14 is available as a first-class language dialect.

Comment: I'm sorry; I'm new to Xcode, but where in the world do you `set "C++ Language Dialect"` ???

Comment: @NickDesaulniers You've probably found it by now but... click on your project in the Project Navigator (on the left by default), you should see a configuration sheet with titles Architectures, Build Locations, Build Options, etc. Scroll down quite a bit. You should see "Apple LLVM 6.0 - Language - C++". Also, take notice of above "Basic | All | Combined | Levels | +": you can apply the settings to the Project or the Target.

Comment: @Olson.dev yes thank you.  Disappointed to see XCode 5.1 only supports up to C++11, meaning I need to upgrade off of OSX 10.8.5 to use it.

Answer (score 0):

With Xcode Version 8.2 (8C38) you click on the project name in the project navigator (click on the little folder at the left of the window to get to this) then in the middle pane of the ide, you click on build settings (up the top of the middle pane), then you can scroll to find the Apple LLVM 8.0 - Language - C++ section. There is a C++ Language Dialect section; select C++14 [-std-c++=14] from the spinner. This then compiles properly.