# Any way to format large numbers in code to make easier to read?

Tags: c++, format

I've done a bit of searching for a solution to this (or a previously asked question on SO), but all that turns up are results for formatting numbers in the output of a program, which is not what I'm looking for.  My question is, are there any solutions to formatting large numbers IN code (not the output of a program) to make them easier to read.

For instance

```
int main()
{
    int LargeNumber = 1000000;
}
```

This number holds 1 million, but its not so easy to tell right away without moving the cursor over it and counting.  Are there any good solutions to this besides using a comment?

```
int main()
{
    int LargeNumber = 1000000;//1,000,000
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is wrong with `1E6` ? At double precision I am pretty sure it will convert to the correct big integer `1000000`. Of course this has limits for VERY big numbers where a 52 bit mantissa does not suffice.

Comment: Never really considered scientific notation before... thanks for the tip.  I'll have to try that out as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current standard allows you to insert apostrophes as separators in literals, so your code would look like:

```
int main()
{
    int LargeNumber = 1'000'000;
}
```

This was added relatively recently (in C++14), however, so if you're using an older compiler, it may not be supported yet. Depending on the compiler, you may also need to add a flag to ask for conformance with the most recent standard to get the compiler to accept this. Offhand I don't remember the exact compiler versions necessary to support it, but it works with the current versions of the major compilers (e.g., g++, clang, and VC++).

Comment: Interesting.  I'm currently using the newest version of Xcode, so I'll have to look into this.

Comment: @joe_04_04: XCode uses a special (since we're not allowed to call it "retarded" any more) version of Clang. I'd *expect* that it supports this (try `-std=c++14`) but I haven't XCode recently, so I can't say for sure.

Comment: I apologize, but I'm not quite sure where that bit of code goes (I still consider myself a novice in C++).  I did try to use apostrophes and it wasn't accepted, but I also didn't know how to implement that short bit of code.

Comment: @joe_04_04: Perhaps [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23018783/179910) will help.

Comment: Thanks a ton.  This helped.  Changing the language dialect to C++14 allowed me to use apostrophes as separators.  Thank you.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: what's special about Apple's `clang`? Never had a problem with it.